# Not stable on using GitHub CLI and Git with GitHub Actions

Tags: git, shell, github-actions

I have a shell script written to check if a branch exists in repositories based on a keyword.

Snippets of the script:

```
for repo_name in ${repository[@]}; do
  gh repo clone $org_name/$repo_name >/dev/null 2>&1
  cd $repo_name
  if [[ -n "$(git branch -r | grep -w $keyword)" ]]; then
    echo "Branch does exist in $org_name/$repo_name"
  else
    echo "Branch does not exist in $org_name/$repo_name"
  fi
  cd ..
  rm -rf $repo_name
done
```

I written a GitHub Actions workflow to continuously execute this script for other purpose.

Now I used a branch named `ABC` to test this script. It works fine in my local, printed the result that the branch does exist in the repository. However, it doesn't work on one of my repository running the GitHub Actions workflow. It just showed me that it does not exist. The funny thing is i tried to create a new repository, setting up same script and workflow, it can show the result correctly like my local.

For example, there are branches named `ABC` in two repository `R1` and `R2` respectively. I executed the same script in local, and another two repository `R3` and `R4` stored the workflow. The result showed as below,

1. local: Branch `ABC` does exist in `R1` and `R2`
2. `R3` workflow: Branch `ABC` does exist in `R1` but not in `R2`
3. `R4` workflow: Branch `ABC` does exist in `R1` and `R2`

`R3` and `R4` used same private key and GitHub Apps to authenticate to the repository during workflow execution.

Can anyone tell me how is it possible? Is it something related to my shell script?

Comment: Cloning seems like overkill if you just want to see if a branch exists - `git ls-remote $URL` would be faster, and it'll also tell you the commit at the head of each branch.

Comment: @JimRedmond I used `gh repo clone` because the script is actually executed by GitHub Actions. I can simply setup a GitHub App to authenticate to my organisation, and use gh cli with the generated token to get the git info for each repository. If I use `git ls-remote` command directly, I would need to download the private key and setup SSH config during the workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Jim commented, you don't need to `clone` them all.

Can use `git ls-remote`, with more params:

```
git ls-remote --heads ${URL} ${KEYWORD}
```

to verify if that branch exists.

So the script would be something like:

```
KEYWORD=my_repo

for repo_name in ${repositories[@]}; do
  URL=gh:$org_name/$repo_name  # see note [1] below.

  if [[ -n $(git ls-remote --heads ${URL} ${KEYWORD}) ]] ; then
    echo "Branch does exist in $org_name/$repo_name"

  else
    echo "Branch does not exist in $org_name/$repo_name"

done
```

#### Note

1. I use ssh to connect to Github with ssh config like this:

```
Host gh
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  User git
  Port 443
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_my_key
```

You may need to change the `URL` to a proper value.

2. the `git ls-remote` command seems not return `1` when the branch is not found.

You can use `[[ -n ... ]]` (like the example above) or use `grep -q ${KEYWORD}` in your if conditions.

---

#### Edited - get branch list with `gh api`

If you can use `gh api`, can install `jq` then filter branches **without cloning** like this:

```
gh api repos/$org_name/$repo_name/branches | jq -r '.[].name' | grep -w ${KEYWORD}

# I prefer grep -q in if statements
# e.g.
# if gh api repos/$org_name/$repo_name/branches | jq -r '.[].name' | grep -q ${KEYWORD} 
# then 
# ...
# fi
```

To install `jq`, see: https://command-not-found.com/jq

Comment: I used `gh repo clone` because the script is actually executed by GitHub Actions. I can simply setup a GitHub App to authenticate to my organisation, and use gh cli with the generated token to get the git info for each repository. If I use `git ls-remote` command directly, I would need to download the private key and setup SSH config during the workflow.

Comment: I see. Then maybe you can use `gh api`. I'll put what I know in edited part of my post

Comment: It is good. Adding --paginate to the `gh api` command would be better if the target repository has many branches. It works fine in my local, and I will try on GitHub Actions later and see if it can fix my issue. Will mark it as answer after i tested.